# Can't add reference System.Windows.Controls in Moonlight

Tags: mono, monodevelop, moonlight

I installed the Moonlight SDK and Monodevelop (latest 2.1 trunk) on both SuSE and Mac OS X.  I noticed System.Windows.Controls.dll is in the Moonlight SDK folder but I can't reference it in my project.  Anyone know why I can't add a reference to this assembly?

Comment: The workaround did work on the SuSE VM.  When adding the reference to Mac OS X, the page no longer displays even without adding any controls to the XAML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pkgconfig-based assembly discovery is broken for the Moonlight SDK. Could you please file a bug?

As a workaround, you should be able to reference the assembly directly as an assembly reference.